# Sharing my keystore with other developers in order to test play-services specific features that require login

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My situation is as follows. I'm developing a game that uses google play services. In order to test multiplayer features, users must be logged in to their account. For the log-in to work, the APK that is uploaded to the play store must have the same signature as the APK that is running on your device. Since the play store does not accept APK that are signed with the debug keystore, I must sign my uploaded APK with my release sign-in config.
Now there are other developers that help me, and I want them to be able to build the app, run it and test the multi player features. The only way they would be able to log in and test the multi player is if they build the APK with the release sign-in config, which I don't want to share for obvious reasons.
My questions is what is the best way to go about this situation? I can create a different keystore that will be used for signing this specific application, then I build the app and upload it to the play store, and give the developers the keystore so they could build the app themselves and test it. Is this the best solution?

Comment: For the testing part, have you tried using the add testers features in the [Google Play Games Console](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub)? There you can add people who can test your game.

Comment: Yes, and while it is necessary to add testers, you still must run the APK with the same signing certificate.